# How to prevent multiples instances of same model

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to know how to prevent multiples instances of the same model in Thymeleaf, example: display the user name on header.

```
<span th:text="${username}">User Name</span>
```

Controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "User Name");
    return "index.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String admin(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "User Name");
    return "indexAdmin.html";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", "User Name");
    return "page.html";
}
```

Comment: You can put the username is session and can access it in thymeleaf and thus you can avoid repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows you to do the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("username")
public String username() {
    return "User Name";
}
```

This code will set a "username" attribute for each request that is being handled by an enclosing controller. You can also get access to almost any parameters that are available for @RequestMapping methods including the model object itself.

As stated in the comment above, if you would like to preserve some object across requests of a particular user (e.g. fetch it from the database and populate the model with that instance) then you can create a @SessionAttributes handler or put the object into the session manually.

It appears that the "thymeleaf" tag could be removed from the question

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As you showed in the sniped code, username model attribute will always be "User Name", isnt it? So... I think @Apollo solutions is more flexible. What you think?

Comment: It depends on your needs. There are just two options. ModelAttribute handler will be invoked on each request. If you would like to persist some object across requests of a particular user (session) then you can use either @SessionAttributes or just put that object manually into the session. If you are setting the username of a logged in user, then (most probably) the user itself is already in the session, right?